# TinyMCE 4 and missing icons in FF/IE

Tags: jquery, apache2, tinymce

I've been trying to get TinyMCE 4.0.11 working, but the icons are not displayed in **IE** and **FF**.

Apparently, TinyMCE requires cross-site scripting to work, so I tried to add this to my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true   - also tried false
</IfModule>
```

I enabled the mod "headers", too.

I also tried creating a php wrapper which enables these properties and forward the font files, with no result.

However, none of this worked. I'm still getting missing icons. I also looked at many other questions here related to this topic and tried everything the answers had to offer, but none of these worked.

This is a log (Firefox) from the font loading process:
[image: Font loading]

Comment: What's under Network tab about those images? I mean if a) those images are really created? b) if it's a http-error?

Comment: I attached a screenshot for you.

Comment: I asked you two questions.

Comment: The fonts are really uploaded. And I don't specifically know what exactly these http errors mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue had to do with Visual Studio. When dragging the "tinymce" folder into the Solution Explorer, the font files get copied into the solution directory and they get **damaged**. Can you believe this?

I really didn't expect *that*. However, I hope I could help someone who had the same problem.

I was using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate by the way.